# OutOfMemoryException when serializing large object tree

Tags: protobuf-net

I am serializing an object that has this structure:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo{
   // some more properties 

   [ProtoMember(100)]
   public IEnumerable<Bar>{get;set}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Bar{
   // a lot of properties
}
```

I am using this code to write the protobuf:

```
 var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 await new ProtoBufFormatter().WriteToStreamAsync(typeof(T), obj, ms, null, null);
```

As soon as the object tree gets over a certain size (10000> and more items) - I end up with an OutOfMemoryException.

I am wondering if there are ways to tell protobuf-net to do a better serialization (to avoid the OutOfMemoryException) or if there are other ways to get around the problem?

**Update**
I get the following exception:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at ProtoBuf.BufferPool.ResizeAndFlushLeft(Byte[]& buffer, Int32 toFitAtLeastBytes, Int32 copyFromIndex, Int32 copyBytes) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\BufferPool.cs:line 60
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.DemandSpace(Int32 required, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 501
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteString(String value, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 600
   at proto_29(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 53
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 752
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 46
   at proto_27(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 53
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 752
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 46
   at proto_23(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 53
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 752
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 46
   at proto_9(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 53
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 752
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 46
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 53
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 752
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.WriteRecursionSafeObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 75
   at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 53
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 752
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 186
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 217
   at WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBufFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
```

Comment: Is there any way you can catch the exception and share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message and full stack trace?  Since you're serializing asynchronously see [Async & exceptions in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/) to catch the exception.

Comment: 1) [Are you running in 32 or 64 bit](How to determine programmatically whether a particular process is 32-bit or 64-bit)?  2) After the exception is thrown, how big is the buffer returned by [`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: That hint solved it! I was running the process as 32-bit. Changing to 64-bit solved it. What is a bit confusing to me: When I call MemoryStream.GetBuffer() I get an empty array...